# Кавычки при перечислении нескольких слов

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, перечисление

Если в предложении приводится пример слов, можно ли всех их объединить под общими кавычками или следует заключать в них обязательно каждое слово?

Например: Я бы хотел поговорить о словах "давеча, недавно, намедни".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я считаю, что необходимо заключать в кавычки каждое слово.
Во-первых, запятые в состав слова не входят.
Во-вторых, достаточно поставить между словами "и" (*«давеча, недавно и намедни»*) — станет понятно, что союз тоже не является частью слова.

Правильно:
**Я бы хотел поговорить о словах «давеча», «недавно», «намедни».**
Я бы хотел поговорить о словах «давеча», «недавно» и «намедни».

Чтобы дать некоторое, очень отдаленное представление о таких словах, указывают обычно на те из наших слов, которые по своему составу не отличаются от корней вроде: «дуб», «кот», «я», «бык», «он»... [Л. В. Успенский. Слово о словах (1971)]

Здесь не должны тревожить такие слова, как "отвернулся", "не поддержал", "погубил", "предал"... [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, ч. 1 (1960)]

Пример из правил Розенталя ([Употребление кавычек](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169))   :
Выделяются кавычками названия:
4) танков (разговорные): *«пантера», «фердинанд», «тридцатьчетверка».*

Несколько слов можно взять в кавычки, если перечисляются дословные выражения (то есть цитаты).

Он говорил такие слова: "дружище", "да, брат", "нет, брат", "вот, брат, какая заковырина получается", ― хоть и окончил институт в Ленинграде. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

Answer (score 0):

Каждое слово отдельно, конечно.
Сама идея объединить их под общими кавычками выглядит несколько абсурдной: во-первых, запятые в закавычиваемое понятие уж точно не входят, а во-вторых, единые кавычки заставляют смотреть на перечисление как на единое целое, что не совсем разумно.
Остальное - см. у @РиммаМихайлова, мне по сути добавить нечего.