# Вот тот / вот та / вот ту — допустимо ли использование таких сочетаний?

Tags: грамотная-речь, частицы

Я прохожу курс финского языка (платное приложение, рекламировать не буду). Приложение показало, что правильный ответ:

> Ты видишь вот ту реку?

[image: 1]

Я поискал в Google сочетание "вот ту", однако не нашёл серьёзных источников, в которых бы упоминалось данное сочетание.

Является ли оно допустимым или тут допущена ошибка?

Comment: Приветствую Вас на форуме. Заковыристый вопрос. Просто для сведения: нельзя заключать в кавычки _вот тот/та/ту/..._ Посмотрите здесь: Кавычки при перечислении нескольких слов (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462543/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2).

Comment: И ещё: слеш в некоторых ситуациях отбивается пробелом. Можно посмотреть **вот** ["вот" — как у Вас в вопросе] здесь: Отбивается ли пробелами косая черта в тексте? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447260/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5/447261#447261)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ты видишь вот ту реку?￼

Никакой ошибки в сочетании "вот ту" нет.

> **[ВОТ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82&all=x)**, частица. <...> 2. (обычно ударная) (с местоим. и нареч.). Употребляется для уточнения и усиления значения последующего
> слова или высказывания в целом.

Несколько примеров из **Нацкорпуса**:

*Видишь **вот ту** сосну?*  [А. И. Куприн. Олеся (1896)]

*И **вот ту** рамочку, что над пианино, он тоже сделал.* [А. П. Чехов. Три сестры (1901)]

*Есть у меня два человека: ты, папаша, да **вот тот** старик.* [И. С. Шмелев. Человек из ресторана (1911)]

*Видишь **вот тот** парус? Он называется «мунсель». За ним уже нет ничего ― только небо.* [Н. К. Чуковский. Водители фрегатов (1927-1941)]

Другие примеры сочетаний "вот тот" и проч. см. [здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2).

Comment: Может быть, Вы правы, но я бы так не смог сказать (разве что там видно несколько рек и говорящий указывает на одну из них, тогда пусть). Оставлю здесь [ссылку по теме](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2015/materials/pdf/KrylovaTV.pdf) (просто для справки, а не как контраргумент).

Answer (score 2):

Бытует устойчивое «вот те на» как возглас удивления. В вашем случае, где ошибки не наблюдается, наряду с  *Вот*, может стоять и *Вон* (в источниках примеров числом не меньше), указывающее на нечто, находящееся на расстоянии:

> Ну-ка, быстро, вон ту балку на верстак и покажи маэстро, как следует выглаживать дерево. [Святослав Логинов. Мастерская Иосифа (2014)]

Comment: Разве здесь "вон" наречие, а не частица? Я в чём-то согласен с Вашим ответом, но если Вы хотели объяснить основное отличие в употреблении частиц "вот" и "вон", то Вам это явно не удалось.

Comment: Да, наврал, Вон (в этом случае) — частица или, по Ожегову, местоимение. Исправляю. Вопрос, который был назван Р.М. заковыристым, не предполагает разбор недоразумения по существу. Отвечая на почти риторический вопрос — допустимо ли? — я дополнил ряд примером с местоимением Те и указал, что также существует вариант с Вон, что более уместно для случая удалённости говорящих от объекта. Но деталей мы не знаем: одно дело водить указкой по карте, другое — с биноклем мерить землю ногами.